MassTransit with Kafka and Lamar Exception
I'm running into an issue when I introduce Lamar into my MassTransit project for Kafka when trying to dynamically connect consumer topics at runtime. I have other projects using Azure Service Bus with Lamar and MassTransit just fine, this is my first Kafka project.
If I do not use Lamar at all to test with, I'm able to resolve IKafkaRider just fine, however, not using Lamar is not a solution here.

Note: Lamar does not add/scan any MassTransit or Confluent assemblies on its own. Everything it receives, it receives from the UseLamar extension method after MassTransit is configured on the IServiceCollection.

I'm getting an error from Lamar when I use either the UsingInMemory extension method within the MassTransit configuration or if I attempt to resolve the IKafkaRider from the container if I do not use the UsingInMemory extension. I imagine the latter is due to not calling the UsingInMemory extension.
Here is the sample code:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var configuration = preHostContainer.GetInstance<IServiceConfiguration>();

builder.Services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    //x.UsingInMemory()
    x.UsingInMemory((context, config) => config.ConfigureEndpoints(context));

    x.AddRider(rider =>
    {
        rider.AddConsumer<GenericKafkaConsumer>();
 
        rider.UsingKafka((riderContext, kafkaConfig) =>
        {
            kafkaConfig.Host(configuration.KafkaSettings.Broker, kafkaHostConfig =>
            {
                kafkaHostConfig.UseSasl(p =>
                {
                    p.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.SaslSsl;
                    p.Mechanism = SaslMechanism.Plain;
                    p.Username = configuration.KafkaSettings.SaslUsername;
                    p.Password = configuration.KafkaSettings.SaslPassword;
                });
            });
        });
    });
});

builder.Host.UseLamar((context, registry) =>
{
    registry.IncludeRegistry<AppRegistry>();
});

var webApp = builder.Build();

await webApp.StartAsync(token);

// Exception here if I do not call .UsingInMemory in MT config
var connector = webApp.Services.GetRequiredService<IKafkaRider>();

// wire up consumers at runtime here

Exception if I call x.UsingInMemory when configuring MassTransit:
An error occurred starting the application. See exception message for details.
Message: Detected some kind of bi-directional dependency while trying to discover and plan a missing service registration. Examining types: Confluent.Kafka.ClientConfig
Type: System.InvalidOperationException
Source: Lamar
Stack Trace:
   at Lamar.ServiceGraph.TryToCreateMissingFamily(Type serviceType)
   at Lamar.ServiceGraph.addMissingFamily(Type serviceType)
   at Lamar.ServiceGraph.ResolveFamily(Type serviceType)
   at Lamar.ServiceGraph.FindDefault(Type serviceType)
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.ConstructorInstance.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<couldBuild>b__0(ParameterInfo p)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.All[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.ConstructorInstance.couldBuild(ConstructorInfo ctor, ServiceGraph services)
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.ConstructorInstance.<>c__DisplayClass42_0.<DetermineConstructor>b__1(ConstructorInfo x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetFirst[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate, Boolean& found)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.ConstructorInstance.DetermineConstructor(ServiceGraph services, String& message)
   at Lamar.ServiceGraph.CouldBuild(Type concreteType, String& message)
   at Lamar.ConcreteFamilyPolicy.Build(Type type, ServiceGraph serviceGraph)
   at Lamar.ServiceGraph.<>c__DisplayClass66_0.<TryToCreateMissingFamily>b__1(IFamilyPolicy x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetFirst[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate, Boolean& found)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at JasperFx.Core.EnumerableExtensions.FirstValue[TItem,TReturn](IEnumerable`1 enumerable, Func`2 func)
   at Lamar.ServiceGraph.TryToCreateMissingFamily(Type serviceType)
   at Lamar.ServiceGraph.addMissingFamily(Type serviceType)
   at Lamar.ServiceGraph.ResolveFamily(Type serviceType)
   at Lamar.ServiceGraph.FindResolver(Type serviceType)
   at Lamar.IoC.Scope.TryGetInstance(Type serviceType)
   at Lamar.IoC.Scope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at MassTransit.Configuration.RegistrationContext.GetService(Type serviceType) in /_/src/MassTransit/DependencyInjection/Configuration/RegistrationContext.cs:line 129
   at MassTransit.Configuration.RiderRegistrationContext.GetService(Type serviceType) in /_/src/MassTransit/DependencyInjection/Configuration/RiderRegistrationContext.cs:line 30
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at MassTransit.KafkaIntegration.Configuration.KafkaRegistrationRiderFactory.CreateRider(IRiderRegistrationContext context) in /_/src/Transports/MassTransit.KafkaIntegration/KafkaIntegration/Configuration/KafkaRegistrationRiderFactory.cs:line 29
   at MassTransit.Configuration.ServiceCollectionRiderConfigurator.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`1.<SetRiderFactory>b__4(IServiceProvider provider) in /_/src/MassTransit/DependencyInjection/Configuration/ServiceCollectionRiderConfigurator.cs:line 54
   at Lamar.IoC.Resolvers.SingletonLambdaResolver`2.Build(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.IoC.Resolvers.SingletonResolver`1.Resolve(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.LambdaInstance`2.Resolve(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.Instance.QuickResolve(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.IoC.Frames.InjectedServiceField.ToVariableExpression(LambdaDefinition definition)
   at JasperFx.CodeGeneration.Expressions.LambdaDefinition.ExpressionFor(Variable variable)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectArrayIterator`2.Fill(ReadOnlySpan`1 source, Span`1 destination, Func`2 func)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectArrayIterator`2.ToArray()
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.CollectionExtensions.ToReadOnly[T](IEnumerable`1 enumerable)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.NewArrayInit(Type type, IEnumerable`1 initializers)
   at Lamar.IoC.Frames.ListAssignmentFrame`1.WriteExpressions(LambdaDefinition definition)
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.FuncResolverDefinition.BuildResolver()
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.GeneratedInstance.BuildFuncResolver(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.GeneratedInstance.buildResolver(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.GeneratedInstance.ToResolver(Scope topScope)
   at Lamar.ServiceGraph.FindResolver(Type serviceType)
   at Lamar.IoC.Scope.GetInstance(Type serviceType)
   at Lamar.Container.Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ISupportRequiredService.GetRequiredService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at MassTransit.Configuration.ServiceCollectionBusConfigurator.CreateBus[T](T busFactory, IServiceProvider provider) in /_/src/MassTransit/DependencyInjection/Configuration/ServiceCollectionBusConfigurator.cs:line 118
   at MassTransit.Configuration.ServiceCollectionBusConfigurator.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<SetBusFactory>b__0(IServiceProvider provider) in /_/src/MassTransit/DependencyInjection/Configuration/ServiceCollectionBusConfigurator.cs:line 82
   at Lamar.IoC.Resolvers.SingletonLambdaResolver`2.Build(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.IoC.Resolvers.SingletonResolver`1.Resolve(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.LambdaInstance`2.<ToResolver>b__14_0(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.ServiceGraph.<>c__DisplayClass58_0.<FindResolver>b__0(Scope s)
   at Lamar.IoC.Scope.GetInstance(Type serviceType)
   at Lamar.Container.Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ISupportRequiredService.GetRequiredService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at MassTransit.Configuration.ServiceCollectionBusConfigurator.<>c__3`1.<SetBusFactory>b__3_1(IServiceProvider provider) in /_/src/MassTransit/DependencyInjection/Configuration/ServiceCollectionBusConfigurator.cs:line 84
   at Lamar.IoC.Resolvers.SingletonLambdaResolver`2.Build(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.IoC.Resolvers.SingletonResolver`1.Resolve(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.LambdaInstance`2.Resolve(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.Instance.QuickResolve(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.IoC.Enumerables.ListInstance`1.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<QuickResolve>b__0(Instance x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectArrayIterator`2.Fill(ReadOnlySpan`1 source, Span`1 destination, Func`2 func)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectArrayIterator`2.ToList()
   at Lamar.IoC.Enumerables.ListInstance`1.QuickResolve(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.ConstructorInstance.<>c__DisplayClass27_0.<quickResolve>b__0(CtorArg x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectArrayIterator`2.Fill(ReadOnlySpan`1 source, Span`1 destination, Func`2 func)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectArrayIterator`2.ToArray()
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.ConstructorInstance.quickResolve(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.ConstructorInstance.QuickResolve(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.IoC.Enumerables.ListInstance`1.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<QuickResolve>b__0(Instance x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectArrayIterator`2.Fill(ReadOnlySpan`1 source, Span`1 destination, Func`2 func)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectArrayIterator`2.ToList()
   at Lamar.IoC.Enumerables.ListInstance`1.QuickResolve(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.ConstructorInstance.<>c__DisplayClass27_0.<quickResolve>b__0(CtorArg x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectArrayIterator`2.Fill(ReadOnlySpan`1 source, Span`1 destination, Func`2 func)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectArrayIterator`2.ToArray()
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.ConstructorInstance.quickResolve(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.ConstructorInstance.QuickResolve(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.ConstructorInstance.<>c__DisplayClass27_0.<quickResolve>b__0(CtorArg x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectArrayIterator`2.Fill(ReadOnlySpan`1 source, Span`1 destination, Func`2 func)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectArrayIterator`2.ToArray()
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.ConstructorInstance.quickResolve(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.ConstructorInstance.QuickResolve(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.ConstructorInstance.<>c__DisplayClass27_0.<quickResolve>b__0(CtorArg x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectArrayIterator`2.Fill(ReadOnlySpan`1 source, Span`1 destination, Func`2 func)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectArrayIterator`2.ToArray()
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.ConstructorInstance.quickResolve(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.ConstructorInstance.QuickResolve(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.ConstructorInstance.<>c__DisplayClass27_0.<quickResolve>b__0(CtorArg x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectArrayIterator`2.Fill(ReadOnlySpan`1 source, Span`1 destination, Func`2 func)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectArrayIterator`2.ToArray()
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.ConstructorInstance.quickResolve(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.ConstructorInstance.QuickResolve(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.IoC.Frames.InjectedServiceField.ToVariableExpression(LambdaDefinition definition)
   at JasperFx.CodeGeneration.Expressions.LambdaDefinition.ExpressionFor(Variable variable)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectArrayIterator`2.Fill(ReadOnlySpan`1 source, Span`1 destination, Func`2 func)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectArrayIterator`2.ToArray()
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.CollectionExtensions.ToReadOnly[T](IEnumerable`1 enumerable)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.NewArrayInit(Type type, IEnumerable`1 initializers)
   at Lamar.IoC.Frames.ListAssignmentFrame`1.WriteExpressions(LambdaDefinition definition)
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.FuncResolverDefinition.BuildResolver()
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.GeneratedInstance.BuildFuncResolver(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.GeneratedInstance.buildResolver(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.GeneratedInstance.ToResolver(Scope topScope)
   at Lamar.ServiceGraph.FindResolver(Type serviceType)
   at Lamar.IoC.Scope.GetInstance(Type serviceType)
   at Lamar.Container.Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ISupportRequiredService.GetRequiredService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\source\test-app\src\Test.App\Program.cs:line 125

Exception if I do not calll x.UsingInMemory in the MassTransit config and attempt to resolve IKafkaRider:
An error occurred starting the application. See exception message for details.
Message: No service registrations exist for MassTransit.DependencyInjection.Bind<MassTransit.IBus, MassTransit.Transports.IBusInstance> or can be derived because:
Cannot fill the dependencies of any of the public constructors
Available constructors:new Bind<MassTransit.IBus, MassTransit.Transports.IBusInstance>(IBusInstance value)
* IBusInstance is not registered within this container and cannot be auto discovered by any missing family policy

Type: Lamar.IoC.LamarMissingRegistrationException
Source: Lamar
Stack Trace:
   at Lamar.IoC.Scope.GetInstance(Type serviceType)
   at Lamar.Container.Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ISupportRequiredService.GetRequiredService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at MassTransit.Configuration.ServiceCollectionRiderConfigurator.<>c__2`1.<SetRiderFactory>b__2_5(IServiceProvider provider) in /_/src/MassTransit/DependencyInjection/Configuration/ServiceCollectionRiderConfigurator.cs:line 55
   at Lamar.IoC.Resolvers.SingletonLambdaResolver`2.Build(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.IoC.Resolvers.SingletonResolver`1.Resolve(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.LambdaInstance`2.<ToResolver>b__14_0(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.ServiceGraph.<>c__DisplayClass58_0.<FindResolver>b__0(Scope s)
   at Lamar.IoC.Scope.GetInstance(Type serviceType)
   at Lamar.Container.Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ISupportRequiredService.GetRequiredService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at MassTransit.Configuration.ServiceCollectionRiderConfigurator.<>c__2`1.<SetRiderFactory>b__2_6(IServiceProvider provider) in /_/src/MassTransit/DependencyInjection/Configuration/ServiceCollectionRiderConfigurator.cs:line 56
   at Lamar.IoC.Resolvers.SingletonLambdaResolver`2.Build(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.IoC.Resolvers.SingletonResolver`1.Resolve(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.IoC.Instances.LambdaInstance`2.<ToResolver>b__14_0(Scope scope)
   at Lamar.ServiceGraph.<>c__DisplayClass58_0.<FindResolver>b__0(Scope s)
   at Lamar.IoC.Scope.GetInstance(Type serviceType)
   at Lamar.Container.Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ISupportRequiredService.GetRequiredService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\source\test-app\src\Test.App\Program.cs:line 135

Here is what Lamar has registered if I do not call x.UsingInMemory:
======================================================================================================================================================================================================================
ServiceType                                                Namespace                           Lifecycle     Description                                                                     Name
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bind<IBus, ISetScopedConsumeContext>                       MassTransit.DependencyInjection     Singleton     Lambda Factory of Bind<MassTransit.IBus, MassTransit.ISetScopedConsumeCo...     Bind<MassTransit.IBus,...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bind<IBus, IScopedConsumeContextProvider>                  MassTransit.DependencyInjection     Scoped        Lambda Factory of Bind<MassTransit.IBus, MassTransit.DependencyInjection...     Bind<MassTransit.IBus,...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bind<IBus, IBusRegistrationContext>                        MassTransit.DependencyInjection     Singleton     Lambda Factory of Bind<MassTransit.IBus, MassTransit.IBusRegistrationCon...     Bind<MassTransit.IBus,...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bind<IBus, IBusInstanceSpecification>                      MassTransit.DependencyInjection     Singleton     Lambda Factory of Bind<MassTransit.IBus, MassTransit.Configuration.IBusI...     Bind<MassTransit.IBus,...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bind<IBus, IClientFactory>                                 MassTransit.DependencyInjection     Singleton     Lambda Factory of Bind<MassTransit.IBus, MassTransit.IClientFactory>            Bind<MassTransit.IBus,...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bind<IBus, IKafkaRider>                                    MassTransit.DependencyInjection     Singleton     Lambda Factory of Bind<MassTransit.IBus, MassTransit.IKafkaRider>               Bind<MassTransit.IBus,...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bind<IBus, IKafkaRider, IRiderRegistrationContext>         MassTransit.DependencyInjection     Singleton     Lambda Factory of Bind<MassTransit.IBus, MassTransit.IKafkaRider, MassTr...     Bind<MassTransit.IBus,...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bind<IBus, Rider, IConsumerRegistration>                   MassTransit.DependencyInjection     Singleton     User Supplied Object                                                            Bind<MassTransit.IBus,...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bind<IBus, IKafkaRider, ISetScopedConsumeContext>          MassTransit.DependencyInjection     Singleton     Lambda Factory of Bind<MassTransit.IBus, MassTransit.IKafkaRider, MassTr...     Bind<MassTransit.IBus,...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bind<IBus, IKafkaRider, IScopedConsumeContextProvider>     MassTransit.DependencyInjection     Scoped        Lambda Factory of Bind<MassTransit.IBus, MassTransit.IKafkaRider, MassTr...     Bind<MassTransit.IBus,...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ConsumeContext                                             MassTransit                         Scoped        Lambda Factory of ConsumeContext                                                ConsumeContext
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IBusDepot                                                  MassTransit                         Singleton     new BusDepot(instances, logger)                                                 busDepot
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IBusRegistrationContext                                    MassTransit                         Singleton     Lambda Factory of IBusRegistrationContext                                       IBusRegistrationContext
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IClientFactory                                             MassTransit                         Singleton     Lambda Factory of IClientFactory                                                IClientFactory
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IKafkaRider                                                MassTransit                         Singleton     Lambda Factory of IKafkaRider                                                   IKafkaRider
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IPublishEndpoint                                           MassTransit                         Scoped        Lambda Factory of IPublishEndpoint                                              IPublishEndpoint
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IReceiveEndpointDispatcher<>                               MassTransit.Transports              Singleton     new ReceiveEndpointDispatcher<>()                                               receiveEndpointDispatcher
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IReceiveEndpointDispatcherFactory                          MassTransit.Transports              Singleton     Lambda Factory of IReceiveEndpointDispatcherFactory                             IReceiveEndpointDispat...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IRequestClient<>                                           MassTransit                         Scoped        new GenericRequestClient<>()                                                    genericRequestClient
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IRoutingSlipExecutor                                       MassTransit                         Scoped        Lambda Factory of IRoutingSlipExecutor                                          IRoutingSlipExecutor
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IScopedBusContextProvider<IBus>                            MassTransit.DependencyInjection     Scoped        new ScopedBusContextProvider<IBus>()                                            scopedBusContextProvider
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IScopedConsumeContextProvider                              MassTransit.DependencyInjection     Scoped        Lambda Factory of IScopedConsumeContextProvider                                 IScopedConsumeContextP...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ISendEndpointProvider                                      MassTransit                         Scoped        Lambda Factory of ISendEndpointProvider                                         ISendEndpointProvider
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ITopicProducerProvider                                     MassTransit                         Scoped        Lambda Factory of ITopicProducerProvider                                        ITopicProducerProvider
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ScopedConsumeContextProvider                               MassTransit.DependencyInjection     Scoped        new ScopedConsumeContextProvider()                                              scopedConsumeContextPr...
======================================================================================================================================================================================================================

What do I need to do to address the bi-directional dependency exception in Lamar when using the x.UsingInMemory extension method or manually wire up the IBusInstance for Lamar when not using the extension method?

I found the solution. The problem lies with how Lamar does greediest constructor selection found here: https://jasperfx.github.io/lamar/documentation/ioc/registration/constructor-selection/
The solution was to specify the constructor for Lamar to use when it's attempting to resolve the Confluent.Kafka.ClientConfig. Looking at the source for ClientConfig, the constructor Lamar was attempting to use takes in another instance of ClientConfig, resulting in the bi-directionaly dependency exception being thrown.
I added the following to my AppRegistry class which resolved the exception.
ForConcreteType<ClientConfig>().Configure.SelectConstructor(() => new ClientConfig());

